# Ошибка "WindowsError" при попытке переименовать файл с помощью os.rename()

Tags: python, django, python-2.x

**Окружение:**

Windows 8

Python 2.7.9

Django 1.6

openpyxl (для работы с файлами формата "*.xlsx")

**Основная задача:**
Получить от пользователя файл формата "*.xlsx", прочитать его и загрузить данные в Систему.

**Шаг на котором возникает проблема:**
попытка переименовать файл (для приведения к нужному типу)

**Traceback:**

```
File "C:\PythonPtoject\venv\Mygtn\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\PythonPtoject\project\MyGtn\MyGtn\AppGtn\views.py" in appgtn_import_in_system
  266.     os.rename(abs_file_data,abs_file_data_path + '.' + file_extension)

Exception Type: WindowsError at /register/import_in_system/
Exception Value: 32 ������� �� ����� �������� ������ � �����
```

**Пояснения:**

Для получения файла от пользователя использую простой html ("<" и ">" убрал специльно):

```
form action="/register/import_in_system/" method="post" 
    enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}

    input type="file" name="file_to_import">
    button type="submit">Загрузить файл импорта</button>

/form
```

После выбора пользователем файла и нажатия кнопки "Загрузить файл импорта" файл сохраняется во временную папку (механизм сохранения по умолчанию) с расширением "*.upload"

Пример: `C:\users\sss\appdata\local\temp\t6rjr4.upload`

Данное расширение openpyxl не понимает, поэтому я пытаюсь переименовать файл, а точнее сменить у него расширение с "*.upload" на "*.xlsx" используя os.rename()

код с переименованием:

```
abs_file_data  = 'c:\\users\\sss\\appdata\\local\\temp\\t6rjr4.upload' # (текущий абсолютный путь до файла)
abs_file_data_path  = 'c:\\users\\sss\\appdata\\local\\temp\\t6rjr4' # (абсолютный путь до файла без расширения)
file_extension = u'xlsx' # (новое расширение файла) 
os.rename(abs_file_data,abs_file_data_path + '.' + file_extension)
```

Но при попытке выполнить эту строчку возникает указанная выше ошибка.

Comment: Убедитесь, что никто `.upload` файл не держит открытым или используйте `os.replace()` (порт с Питона 3 на Питон 2).

Comment: *Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл занят другим процессом*

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте переименовывать не после загрузки, а средствами Django указывать правильный путь загрузки (вместе с названием файла)

```
def content_file_name(instance, filename):
    ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    filename = "%s_%s.%s" % (instance.user.id, instance.id, ext)
    return os.path.join('uploads', filename)


class MyFileUpload(models.Model):
    # ...
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=content_file_name)
```